# FindControl() always returns null from DataList Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have 8 items in a SQL table with a Description, ItemNumber, and ImagePath.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //fill the datalist for the Signs Table
        string tCallFrom = "Program." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        string tQry = @"SELECT * FROM [js_Signs]";

        DataTable tblSigns = objCommMethods.fReturnTableFromQry(clsDBSelect.enumDBSelect.ProjectMaster, tQry, tCallFrom);

        SignsList.DataSource = tblSigns;
        SignsList.DataBind();
    }
```

I am using a DataList to show all of the items along with a textbox that will allow a user to input the number of items they want:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="SignsList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="2" Width="90%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemNumber") %>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Image ID="SignImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImagePath") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSignQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" BackColor="White" Enabled="true" 
                                            type="number" min="0" ToolTip="Please choose quantity of signs needed."/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <p> </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
             <div class="btnGroup">
                <div class="btnDiv">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btnSave" Width="90px" Visible="true" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
                </div>
                <div class="btnDiv">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Clear" CssClass="btnCancel" Width="90px" Visible="true" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

After the saved button is clicked in C# I want to find out the value that a user entered but it is always returning null:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TextBox txtSignQuantity;
        string tempSignQuantity;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataListItem item in SignsList.Items)
            {
                txtSignQuantity = item.FindControl("txtSignQuantity") as TextBox;
                tempSignQuantity = txtSignQuantity.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }   
}
```

I also checked and the Count of SignsList.Items was 8, so I know that it is retrieving the correct information. Sorry, I've never used a Data List before so I'm not really sure how to go about this...

Comment: What's the context of that code? Is it in `Page_Load`?  In a `Click` event handler?

Comment: Oooh sorry I should've put that. It is in a click even handler

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show the full event handler method.  Also, it might help to show where and how you're data-binding the DataList.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for the advice, I went ahead and added that to my post.

Comment: IIRC, you shouldn't do data binding on postback. Wrap the data binding in `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {...}`

Comment: @madreflection That just fixed my problem!! That makes sense now, I just hadn't thought about it. You should put this as an answer and not just a comment so I can give you credit :)

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to determine *why* databinding on postback made it unable to find the control. You'll have to set some breakpoints and investigate changes to the `Items` collection over time. My hope is that the latter part of my answer gives you enough information to figure out how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that data binding on postback is causing the problem.  Check the `Page.IsPostBack` property before doing data binding:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //fill the datalist for the Signs Table
        string tCallFrom = "Program." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        string tQry = @"SELECT * FROM [js_Signs]";
        DataTable tblSigns = objCommMethods.fReturnTableFromQry(clsDBSelect.enumDBSelect.ProjectMaster, tQry, tCallFrom);

        SignsList.DataSource = tblSigns;
        SignsList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ASP.NET WebForms attempts to abstract away the fact that the control instances that were used to render the page are not the same instances it has when handling postback events.  Data binding compounds the abstraction because it has to create controls in response to the `DataBind` call, and then on postback, recreate them based on the `ViewState` it saved.

Initializing controls from `ViewState` happens on the `Init` event, so when the `Load` event is fired later in the page lifecycle and you call `DataBind` on the control, everything it restored gets wiped out and recreated.

As for why you were getting `null`, it may have been that the controls were wiped out but not recreated; it may have had to do with other event handlers that didn't get rewired after the second data binding.